# How can I summarize in each row all the above rows?

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum, libreoffice-base

Is it possible to get sum of all the above rows in each row?

Example:

```
Rows | Count
 1. | 20
 2. | 30
 3. | 10
 4. | 25
```

And I want to take the follow result

```
Rows | TotalCount
  1  | 20    (20)
  2  | 50    (20+30) 
  3  | 60    (20+30+10)
  4  | 85    (20+30+10+25)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You are looking for *running total* e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server

Comment: I am using the LibreOffice Base

Answer (score 1):

You want a cumulative sum.  In standard SQL, you use a window function for this:

```
select rows, sum(count) over (order by rows)
from t;
```